# Amazon Location map how to enable Route calculator, tracker map in react js project

Tags: java, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, geolocation

I need your help to implement the [AWS map](https://console.aws.amazon.com/location/explore/home?region=us-east-1#/route), I have created the Arn for all the required map functionality but I don't know how to enable the search box and its functionality.

1. Map --> implemented
2. Place index --> need help
3. Route calculator --> need help
4. Geofence collection --> need help
5. Tracker --> need help

sample code for your reference:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { createRequestTransformer } from "amazon-location-helpers";
import { ICredentials } from "@aws-amplify/core";
import Amplify,{ Auth } from "aws-amplify";
import ReactMapGL, { NavigationControl, ViewportProps } from "react-map-gl";
import "maplibre-gl/dist/maplibre-gl.css";
import amplifyConfig from "../aws-exports";
Amplify.configure(amplifyConfig);
// Replace with the name of the map that you created on the Amazon Location Service console: https://console.aws.amazon.com/location/maps/home
const mapName = "<MAP NAME>";
const Map = () => {
  const [credentials, setCredentials] = useState<ICredentials>();
  const [transformRequest, setRequestTransformer] = useState<Function>();
  const [viewport, setViewport] = React.useState<Partial<ViewportProps>>({
    longitude: -123.1187,
    latitude: 49.2819,
    zoom: 10,
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchCredentials = async () => {
      setCredentials(await Auth.currentUserCredentials());
    };

    fetchCredentials();
  }, []);
  // create a new transformRequest function whenever the credentials change
  useEffect(() => {
    const makeRequestTransformer = async () => {
      if (credentials != null) {
        const tr = await createRequestTransformer({
          credentials,
          region: amplifyConfig.aws_project_region,
        });
        // wrap the new value in an anonymous function to prevent React from recognizing it as a
        // function and immediately calling it
        setRequestTransformer(() => tr);
      }
    };
    makeRequestTransformer();
  }, [credentials]);
  return (
    <div>
      {transformRequest ? (
        <ReactMapGL
          {...viewport}
          width="100%"
          height="100vh"
           /** @ts-ignore */
          transformRequest={transformRequest}
          mapStyle={mapName}
          onViewportChange={setViewport}
        >
          <div style={{ position: "absolute", left: 20, top: 20 }}>
            <NavigationControl showCompass={false} />
          </div>
        </ReactMapGL>
      ) : (
        <h1>Loading...</h1>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
export default Map;
```

reference image: [image]

I don't know how to enable the tracker and place index functionality can I get anyone help on this. Thanks in advance.